# Inserting xml nodes in an existing xml document with python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to insert xml nodes in this document:

```
</providers>

</root>
```

I wrote this code:
    import xml.dom.minidom as m

```
doc = m.parse("monfichier.xml")
valeurs = doc.getElementsByTagName("providers")
element = doc.createElement("provider")
valeurs.appendChild(element)

elthost = doc.createElement("hostnamep") 
eltLTVC = doc.createElement("LocalTrustValueC")
element.appendchild(elthost)
element.appendchild(eltLTVC)

texteHost = doc.createTextNode("machinename")
texteLTVC = doc.createTextNode("23") 
eltHost.appendChild(texteHost)
eltLTVC.appendChild(texteLTVC)
doc.writexml(open("monfichier.xml","w"))
```

And I want to obtain at the end this xml document : 
    
    
    
        
            machinename
            23

```
    </provider> 
</providers>

</root>
```

But I obtained this error : 
    valeurs.appendChild(element)
    AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'appendChild'

Comment: Such operations are much easier to express with XSLT. Would you be interested in an XSLT solution?

Comment: Thank you, but I am interested in XML using xml.dom.minidom Any help is appreciated

Comment: Be aware that it is waste of time not to use XSLT for any XML transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So what would be the XSLT solution?

Comment: I just posted a complete XSLT solution. Note that the first template is standard and nobody has to think to invent it -- it is even added by default by some XSLT IDE's. So you just match the element to which you want to add children, and specify these children literally in-line.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. But really I didn't understand very well because I know nothing about XSLT and I am just a beginner in developement  that's why I am asking for a simple and fast solution with python and XML. Thanks again

Comment: XSLT doesn't actually modify a document in place, it creates a whole new one from an input document and set of rules. If you're making a relatively minor change to a large document (such as inserting, modifying or removing a single element), it's a serious waste of resources to include an XSLT processor library and stylesheet, when a few lines of python should do the job.

Comment: Yes I just want to insert an element in an exiting xml document with python. Can you tell me how please?

Comment: ness kh: Even in this very simple case, the complete XSLT solution is shorter than a complete Python one. Also, had you simply used the XSLT solution, you'd have long ago forgotten about this problem. Trying to find a Python solution -- you are still at the very starting point -- isn't this waste of time and resources? In particular because you are a new developer, it is good to know that transformation of an XML document is most easy and straight-forward when expressed with XSLT -- a language that was specifically designed for XML transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some quick reading of http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#dom-node-objects it appears that NodeList does not have an appendChild method. Instead you want to get the first Node in the result set(since your post implies there is only one) and call appendChild on that node.

```
valeurs = doc.getElementsByTagName("providers").item(0)
element = doc.createElement("provider")
valeurs.appendChild(element)
```

Comment: After testing you proposition I get another error related to "element": element.appendchild(elthost)
AttributeError: Element instance has no attribute 'appendchild'

Comment: Can't remember, is python case sensitive? your comment refers to 'appendchild' without a lower case 'c' in 'child'. Did you try the code with a capital C?

Comment: Really thank you very much Flynn. This was just my error.A careless mistake!

Answer (score 2):

As per the OP's interest in an XSLT solution:

**Here is a complete and short XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="providers">
  <providers>
        <provider>
            <hostnamep>machinename</hostnamep>
            <LocalTrustValueC>23</LocalTrustValueC>
        </provider>
  </providers>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <providers> 
    </providers>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <providers>
      <provider>
         <hostnamep>machinename</hostnamep>
         <LocalTrustValueC>23</LocalTrustValueC>
      </provider>
   </providers>
</root>
```