# Add duplicate child tag in existing xml

Tags: python-2.7, xml.etree

sample.py

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
log_file=open("filename.xml","a")
root = ET.Element("VOD")
doc = ET.Element("SessionDetails")
root.append(doc)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

o/p on running sample.py 3 time

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<VOD>

<SessionDetails/>

</VOD>
```

[Note :I am not getting below output]Desired o/p is if I run sample.py 3 times the o/p should be as below

```
-<VOD>

<SessionDetails/>
<SessionDetails/>
<SessionDetails/>

</VOD>
```

Comment: Okay. So what's your question?

Comment: I am not getting desired output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got result using below method

First time XML creation

```
from xml.dom.minidom import getDOMImplementation
impl = getDOMImplementation()
newdoc = impl.createDocument(None, "VOD", None)
top_element = newdoc.documentElement
text = newdoc.createElement('SessionDetaild')
top_element.appendChild(text)
newdoc.writexml(open("filename.xml","w"))
```

For appending data in xml

```
import xml.dom.minidom as m
doc = m.parse("filename.xml")
valeurs = doc.getElementsByTagName("VOD").item(0)
element = doc.createElement("SessionDetaild")
valeurs.appendChild(element)
doc.writexml(open("filename.xml","w"))
```

Reference:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074021/inserting-xml-nodes-in-an-existing-xml-document-with-python
```